# Understanding OOPC, am I doing it right?

Tags: c, oop

I followed Alex's book on object oriented programming using ansi c.

So far tried to model a very basic string class -

Here's the code:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "class.h"
#include "mystring.h"

extern const void *String_c;

int main() {
        String *my = new(String_c, "A random string");
        char *text = my->str(my);
        printf("String contains %s of length %d", text, my->length(my));
        delete(my);
        free(text);
        return 0;
}
```

**class.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_H_
#define CLASS_H_

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
        size_t size;
        void* (*ctor) (void* self, va_list *app);
        void (*dtor) (void* self);
} Class;

void* new(const void *class, ...);
void delete(void *object);

#endif /* CLASS_H_ */
```

**class.c**

```
/*
 * class.c
 *
 *  Created on: 22-Mar-2014
 *      Author: nilesh
 */

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "class.h"

void *new(const void *_class, ...) {
        printf("\nCreating new\n");
        const Class *class = _class;
        void *p = calloc(1, class->size);
        assert(p);
        * (const Class **) p = class;
        if(class->ctor) {
                va_list ap;
                va_start(ap, _class);
                p = class->ctor(p, &ap);
                va_end(ap);
        }
        return p;
}

void delete(void *object) {
        printf("\nDelete\n");
        const Class **class = object;
        if(object && *class && (*class)->dtor)
                (*class)->dtor(object);
        free(object);
        object = NULL;
}
```

**mystring.h**

```
#ifndef STRING_H_
#define STRING_H_

#include <stddef.h>

#include "class.h"

typedef struct string String;

struct _string;

struct string {
        const Class *class;
        struct _string *_;
        int (*length) (String *self);
        char* (*str) (String *self);
};

extern Class _string_class;
extern const void *String_c;

#endif /* STRING_H_ */
```

**mystring.c**

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "mystring.h"

struct _string {
        char *data;
        int length;
};

static int length(String *self) {
        return self->_->length;
}

static char* str(String *self) {
        char *ret = malloc(sizeof(char) * self->_->length);
        memcpy(ret, self->_->data, sizeof(char)*self->_->length);
        return ret;
}

void* ctor(void *_self, va_list *app) {
        printf("\nConstructor called\n");
        String *self = _self;
        self->_ = malloc(sizeof(struct _string));
        char *text = va_arg(*app, char *);
        self->_->length = strlen(text);
        self->_->data  = malloc(sizeof(char) * self->_->length);
        memcpy(self->_->data, text, sizeof(char) * self->_->length);

        self->length = length;
        self->str = str;

        return self;
}

void dtor(void *_self) {
        printf("\nDestructor called\n");
        String *self = _self;
        free(self->_);
        free(self->_->data);
        self->_->data = NULL;
}

Class _string_class = {sizeof(String), ctor, dtor};
const void *String_c = &_string_class;
```

I have one question:

Why does

```
Class *class = object
```

In delete not work, while

```
Class **class = object
```

Works?

Works in the sense, in former it doesn't call `dtor`, but calls length and in case of latter, the call to function is `(*class)->dtor` which works.

Comment: Can you please give a link or a more precise reference to the book you mention ? IMHO this OOP technique is pretty weird, I'm curious to see who devised it.

Comment: @sirdarius http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf and I found this book on one of SO's answers on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that `class` is of type `Class **`; `class->dtor` would work only if `class` were of type `Class *`.

You're probably getting confused because of the double indirection, so here's a longer explanation:

Think about structures layout. Imagine you have a simple structure like so:

```
struct example {
    int xpto;
    char a[10];
}
```

If you call a function `f()` and pass it a pointer `p` to `struct example`, then `f()` is free to cast such a pointer to `int *`. Dereferencing such a pointer yields the same result as `p->xpto`. That is, `p->xpto` and `*(int *) p` are equivalent. This happens because structure components are layed out in increasing memory addresses. `xpto` is the first member, meaning it's at offset 0. In other words, for any pointer to `struct example`, the first `sizeof(int)` bytes at the address pointed to by `p` belong to `xpto`.

Your string structure was defined as:

```
struct string {
        const Class *class;
        struct _string *_;
        int (*length) (String *self);
        char* (*str) (String *self);
};
```

Which shows that at offset 0 of `struct string` there is a (read-only) pointer to `Class`. When you call `delete(my)` in `main()`, you are giving it a pointer to `struct string` - thus, the first `sizeof(const Class *)` bytes in the address pointed to by `my` are a pointer to a `Class`. Like we did in the example with `struct example` - where we casted `p` to a pointer to the first member - casting such a pointer to `Class **` (first member is a `Class *`, so a pointer to the first member is of type `Class **`) gives direct access to the first field (and only the first).

Because of that, `delete()` casts the pointer you give it to a `Class **`, because by doing so, dereferencing such a pointer yields a `Class *`.

Why doesn't `class->dtor()` work? Because `class` is of type `Class **`, so, `class->dtor`, which is equivalent to `(*class).dtor` is invalid: `*class` is of type `Class *`, it's not a structure, and as such, there is no member named `dtor`. You must use `(*class)->dtor`, since that's the same as `(*(*class)).dtor`.